# How Can I Modify/"Spoof" Standard Browser JS DOM Objects (Window.location) at Runtime?

Tags: javascript, dom, firebug, spoofing

I'd like to dynamically change some of the standard JS DOM objects from within a web browser.

For instance, when I execute:

```
var site = location;
```

I want to specify a new value for my browser's "window.location" object other than the "correct" one (the URL used to access the requested page) at run time, either through a debugger-like interface or even programmatically if need be.

Although Firebug advertises the capability to do something similar via its "DOM Inspector," whenever I try to modify any of the DOM values while I've paused the Javascript via its debugger, it simply ignores the new value I enter.  After doing some research, it seems that this is a known issue according to this bug report: http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=1707 .

Theoretically, I could write a program to simply open up an HTTP socket and emulate a browser "user agent," but this seems like a lot of trouble for my purposes.  While I'm asking, does anyone know a good Java/C# library with functions/objects that emulate HTTP headers and parse the received HTML/JS?  I've long dreamt about the existence of such a library but most of the ones I've tried (Java's Apache HttpClient, C#'s System.Net.HttpWebRequest) are far too low-level to make anything worthwhile with minimal planning and a short period of time.

Thanks in advance for recommendations and advice you can provide!

Comment: [zombie](http://zombie.labnotes.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you want to change the loaded URL you can do that by setting `window.location.href`.
If your intent is to replace DOM buildins then you will be sad to hear, that most build-in objects (host objects) aren't regular JavaScript objects and their behaviour is not clearly defined. Some browsers may allow you to replace and/or extend some objects while in other browsers they won't be replaceable/extendable at all.

If you want to "script a browser" using JavaScript, you should definitly have a look at [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and it's [http module](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/http.html#http.get). There's also a thirdparty module called [html5](https://github.com/aredridel/html5) that simulates the DOM in node.js and even allows the usage of jQuery.

Comment: I don't want to _replace_ the DOM built-ins per se; I'd like to change the return value of `window.location.href` DOM object to something other than the current loaded page.  If we were to use this page as an example, any JavaScript references on the page to the `window.location` object should return a value that I've specified rather than `"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208929/how-can-i-modify-spoof-standard-browser-js-dom-objects-window-location-at-run"`.  "node.js" and "zombie" mentioned by @Raynos are certainly interesting and powerful tools, but do not achieve this goal in their API